# Freebase: Find related topics using MQL

Tags: freebase, mql

On the Freebase website topic pages they have a section called "Related Topics". So for example, in the case of [Toy Story](http://www.freebase.com/view/en/toy_story) it has: Toy Story 2, Cars, Finding Nemo & Monsters, Inc

I've read through examples in the Query Editor, the manual, Stack Overflow and Google but I can't find a way to duplicate that in MQL. Does anyone have any idea how to do that in MQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an internal Freebase only feature and is not available to the public (also, it's going away when the website is relaunched "soon").

Freebase staff have previously said that you should file a request on the [Freebase JIRA](http://bugs.freebase.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa) if you want this feature to be made available publicly, but they seem to use the bug tracker more as a bitbucket than anything else.